# how to split the column into multiple columns using delimeter in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below column in my table

[image]

I would like to split the column using decimeter '-' and create a new column in SQL Server.

Required output

[image]

I used parsename in the query but no success.

```
select 
ID,
PARSENAME(ID,'-', 1) AS EmployeeID from timeus;
```

I checked other posts but not able to solve it.

Can anyone advise how to to split in SQL server?

Comment: You only would like to have the characters BEFORE the first - to make the new column, right? What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Oh, and, don/t do printscreens of data. But provide the scripts to create them, helps people solve this problem with much more ease

Comment: my method would be a combination of LEFT and CHARINDEX (assuming that the IDs can be lengths other than 3, otherwise just use LEFT and 3 as the length). You can even wrap that with a TRY_CAST to convert it to an INT if you want to do any mathematical comparisons later

Comment: @Peter thanks. My data in Azure SQL database. I am using DBveaver IDE

Comment: Then I think the answer should work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to split the data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NotProvided
(
    Category NVARCHAR(50)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.NotProvided
(
    Category
)
VALUES
('103-Local IT-HHH'),
('102-HDHD-2737'),
('104-HHFY-XXX');


SELECT *,
       LEFT(Category, CHARINDEX('-', Category) - 1) as Id
FROM dbo.NotProvided;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use *parsename* like you have tried, like so:

```
select ID, ParseName(Replace(ID, '-', '.'), 3) AS EmployeeID 
from timeus;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring function in MSSQL server.

```
    Select Category,SUBSTRING(Category,1,3) As Employeeid From NotProvided;
```